# functional analysis : problem related to closed graph theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, closed-graph

[image]

the problem above is in [Conway's Functional Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387972455) Page $93$.

it seems to be an application of closed graph theorem

if the inequality were posed the other way it could be much easier

but it is hard to resolve that in this setting

anybody who knows some hint for this?

Comment: Map an element in $\frak X$ to $C(E)$ by restricting its domain to $E$. This is linear and bounded. It's also onto by hypothesis. I think you can get what you want from the Open Mapping Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, consider the restriction map:
$$ \Phi: \mathfrak{X}\to C(E) $$
It is not difficult to show that $\Phi$ is linear and bounded. In fact, $\Phi$ is surjective by the assumptions in the question. Therefore, $\Phi$ admits a factorization by the first isomorphism theorem:
$$ \mathfrak{X}\xrightarrow{P}\frac{\mathfrak{X}}{\ker\Phi} \xrightarrow{\overline{\Phi}} C(E) $$
Here, $P$ is the projection onto the quotient, and $\overline{\Phi}$ is an isomorphism of Banach spaces. Therefore, one can call upon the Bounded Inverse Theorem, which gives that $\overline{\Phi}^{-1}:C(E)\to \mathfrak{X}/\ker\Phi$ is bounded.

We're pretty much done, because we have a bounded map in the right direction. Now, choose any element $g\in C(E)$, and consider the coset $[f] = \overline{\Phi}^{-1}(g)$. Since $\overline{\Phi}^{-1}$ is bounded, we have that:
$$ \left\lVert [f] \right\rVert \leq \lVert \overline{\Phi}^{-1}\rVert \left\lVert g\right\rVert $$
But, by the definition of the quotient space norm, for every $\varepsilon > 1$, one can find an actual element $f'\in \mathfrak{X}$ such that:
$$ \left\lVert f' \right\rVert \leq \varepsilon\left\lVert [f] \right\rVert = \varepsilon \inf_{h\in\ker\Phi} \left\lVert f+h \right\rVert $$
Then, $f'$ is a solution, and satisfies the inequality:
$$ \left\lVert f' \right\rVert \leq \varepsilon \left\lVert [f] \right\rVert \leq \varepsilon \lVert \overline{\Phi}^{-1}\rVert \left\lVert g\right\rVert $$